# How to capture multiple words using regex on this particular text?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to extract the best paying job titles from this sample text:

```
Data Scientist

#1 in Best Paying Jobs

5,100  Projected Jobs $250,000 Median Salary 0.5% Unemployment Rate

Programmer

#2 in Best Paying Jobs

4,000 Projected Jobs $240,000 Median Salary 1.0% Unemployment Rate

SAP Module Consultant

#3 in Best Paying Jobs

3,000 Projected Jobs $220,000 Median Salary 0.2% Unemployment Rate
```

by using the following regex and Perl code.

```perl
use File::Glob;
local $/ = undef;
my $file = @ARGV[0];

open INPUT, "<", $file
    or die "Couldn't open file $!\n";

my $content = <INPUT>;

my $regex = "^\w+(\w+)*$\n\n#(\d+)";

my @arr_found = ($content =~ m/^\w+(\w+)*$\n\n#(\d+)/g);

close (INPUT);
```

Q1: The regex finds only the one-word titles*. How to make it find the  multiple word titles and how to forward (i.e. how to properly capture) those found titles into the Perl array?

Q2: I defined the regex into a Perl variable and tried to use that variable for the regex operation like:

```perl
my @arr_found = ($content =~ m/"$regex"/g);
```

but it gave error. How to make it?

* When I apply the regex `^\w+(\w+)*$\n\n#(\d+)` on Sublime Text 2, it finds only the one word titles.

Comment: Q2: use the `qr//` operator (see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)) to compile regexes. I.e. `my $regex = qr/^\w+(\w+)*$\n\n#(\d+)/;`. You can also combine sub-regexes in this way ie. `my $regex = qr/${subre1}${subre2}${subre3}/;`

Comment: Q1 is a bit unclear. F.ex. the first example: do you want to match `Data Scientist` and `#1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers for your questions:

1. you are capturing the second word only and you do not allow for space in between them. That's why it won't match e.g. `Data Scientist`
2. use the `qr//` operator to compile regexes with dynamic content. The error stems from the `$` in the middle of the regex which Perl regex compiler assumes you got wrong, because `$` should only come at the end of a regex.

The following code should achieve what you want. Note the two-step approach:

1. Find matching text

   - beginning of a line (`^`)
   - one-or-more words separated by white space (`\w+(?:\s+\w+)*`, no need to capture match)
   - 2 line ends (`\n\n`)
   - `#` followed by a number (`\d+`)
   - apply regex multiple times (`/g`) and treat strings as multiple lines (`/m`, i.e. `^` will match *any* beginning of a line in the input text)
2. Split match at line ends (`\n`) and extract the 1st and the 3rd field

   - as we know `$match` will contain three lines, this approach is much easier than writing another regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use File::Slurper qw(read_text);

my $input = read_text($ARGV[0])
    or die "slurp: $!\n";

my $regex = qr/^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\n\n#\d+)/m;

foreach my $match ($input =~ /$regex/g) {
    #say $match;
    my($title, undef, $rank) = split("\n", $match);
    $rank =~ s/^#//;
    say "MATCH '${title}' '${rank}'";
}

exit 0;
```

Test run over the example text you provided in your question.

```
$ perl dummy.pl dummy.txt
MATCH 'Data Scientist' '1'
MATCH 'Programmer' '2'
MATCH 'SAP Module Consultant' '3'
```

---

**UNICODE UPDATE:** as suggested by @Jan's answer the code can be improved like this:

```perl
my $regex = qr/^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\R\R#\d+)/m;
...
    my($title, undef, $rank) = split(/\R/, $match);
```

That is probably the more generic approach, as `UTF-8` is the default for `File::Slurper::read_text()` anyway...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had heard about the `qr//` but have forgotten it totally. The loop part is nice.  Never seen or used the `use feature qw(say);` and `use File::Slurper qw(read_text);` before but they're very practical and fine.

Comment: inside the expression `(?:\s+\w+)*` there is `:` I've tried regexing without it and it didn't changed the output. Could it be a typo? What does it do?

Comment: See [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns): "`(?:pattern)` This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like `()` , but doesn't make backreferences as `()` does" AKA non-capturing group (NCG). When you need to group stuff, but not capture the contents, then this is preferable for a slight performance improvement.

Comment: I was thinking `: ` separately, but it turned out to be the combination `?:` and that makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Why not process line-by-line, simple and easy

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift || die "Usage: $0 file\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (@jobs, $prev_line);

while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    chomp $line;
    next if not $line =~ /\S/;

    if ($line =~ /^\s*#[0-9]/) {
        push @jobs, $prev_line;
    }   

    $prev_line = $line;
}

say for @jobs;
```

This relies on the requirement that the `#N` line is the first non-empty line after the jobs title.

It prints

```
Data Scientist
Programmer
SAP Module Consultant
```

The question doesn't say whether rankings are wanted as well but there is a hint in the regex that they may be. Then, assuming that the ordering in the file is "correct" you can iterate over the array indices and print elements (titles) with their indices (rank).

Or, to be certain, capture them in the regex, `/^\s*#([0-9]+)/`. Then you can directly print both the title and its rank, or perhaps store them in a hash with key-value pairs `rank => title`.

---

As for the regex, there are a few needed corrections. To compose a regex ahead of matching, what is a great idea, you want the [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator. To work with multi-line strings you need the `/m` modifier. (See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).)  The regex itself needs fixing. For example

```
my $regex  = qr/^(.+)?(?:\n\s*)+\n\s*#\s*[0-9]/m;
my @titles = $content =~ /$regex/g
```

what captures a line followed by at least one empty line and then `#N` on another line.

If the ranking of titles is needed as well then capture it, too, and store in a hash

```
my $regex = qr/^(.+)?(?:\n\s*)+\n\s*#\s*([0-9]+)/m;
my %jobs  = reverse  $content =~ /$regex/g;
```

or maybe better not push it with `reverse`-ing the list of matches but iterate through pairs instead

```
my %jobs;
while ($content =~ /$regex/g) {
    $jobs{$2} = $1;
}
```

since with this we can check our "catch" at each iteration, do other processing, etc.  Then you can sort the keys to print in order

```
say "#$_ $jobs{$_}" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %jobs;
```

and just in general pick jobs by their rank as needed.

I think that it's fair to say that the regex here is much more complex than the first program.

Comment: thank you for the answer. well  I wanted to treat the whole text as a single string because it wasn't a very long text and I wanted to see if I can tackle it with just one regex.

Comment: @Romario  By all means, that's how we learn :)  I only meant to offer a simpler approach (in principle crucial in production and with difficult problems: break it up using suitable computing approaches and algorithms, to simplify), not to discourage.  I've added a section on regex, for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You were not taking whitespaces (as in `Data Scientist`) into account:

```
^\w+.*$\R+#(\d+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pA46yp/1/).

---

`\R` is equal to `(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85)` (matches Unicode newlines sequences).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a fine regex. But it didn't  contain how to carry the result set of the regex into the Perl array therefore I couldn't select it with a tick.

Comment: @Romario: No worries, glad to help.